# .NET Voip integration

Tags: .net, mobile, sip, voip, telephony

I have this requirement:

A customer presses a button on a mobile phone. This sends a web service request to the server to initiate a call on customer's behalf. The server makes a phone call, which plays a pre-recorded message from the customer, to a different user. The recipient of the call makes a selection using 1,2,3... on their phone, and then the server sends back the response (in web service format) to the original customer.

I am .NET programmer and not sure what to use on the server side. The phone call has to be initiated by the server and it has to understand the user feedback. What technologies are available for doing that?

(btw, it's not for robocalls, if you are wondering. It's for a certain customer-to-business interaction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a VoIP applications provider that has an HTTP exposed API. Two that are worthy of checking out are tropo.com & anveo.com.

Comment: voxeo.com is another one, though it's expensive from what I recall.

Comment: tropo.com is actually a service from Voxeo that's more targetted at developers with smaller voice apps.